# Enviar múltiplos valores em um input para PHP, usando jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, input

Tenho um script com objetivo de inserir varios ítens em uma lista de um formulário, usando Ajax.

Para cada elemento inserido nesta lista, deve ser adicionado um próximo.

Após inseridos X elementos, ele deve pegar todos os valores e jogar em apenas um input, adicionando ao fim de cada elemento como uma tag `br/`, para via PHP enviar ao MySQL.

Ex:

```
<label>Insira os valores</label>
<ul>
 <li>elemento 1</li>
 <li>elemento 2</li>
 <li>elemento 3</li><span>+ adiciona proximo</span>
</ul>
```

O `submit POST` deve gerar um array (elemento1+elemento2+elemento3) adicionando um `br/` ao final de cada elemento, e enviado apenas em um `input name="elementos"`

Comment: E qual é o problema que está a ter? até onde consegui fazer? onde estão os seus inputs?

Comment: Não sei se entendi mas quer enviar todos elementos adicionado a lista em uma array e assim enviar? Estás usando um formulário? De que forma isso vai ser usado?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode ter uma estrutura mais ou menos do tipo:

```
<label>Insira os valores</label>
<ul id='lista'>
 <li class='item'>elemento 1</li>
 <li class='item'>elemento 2</li>
 <li class='item'>elemento 3</li> 
 <span>+ adiciona proximo</span>
</ul>
```

E então o código

```
var elementos = '';
$('#lista>li').each(function()
           {
              elementos += $(this).html() +"<br/>";                                                             
           });
$('#lista').append(elementos);
```

[Olhe aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/3ca6nucn/1/)

E depois você usa a função do próprio jQuery para ajax [neste link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).